# which way to access a base class property or field in derive class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I m a student. Today I Give the Interview and tell me something new about inheritance

I said the derived class can not access the base class property or field because below program prove that
is why I tell the derived class can not access the base class property or field:

```
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>

class baseclass
{
  public:
    int a;
    baseclass()
    {
        std::cout << "baseclass\n";
    }
};

class deriveclass: public baseclass
{
 public:
    deriveclass()
    {
        std::cout << "derived class\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    baseclass * a=new baseclass();  //ok
    deriveclass * b=new deriveclass();  //ok 

    baseclass * aa=new deriveclass(); //ok        
    deriveclass * bb=new baseclass(); //not ok

    return 0;
}
```

Link:https://onlinegdb.com/SyfhRDF_U

error:

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:30:36: error: invalid conversion from ‘baseclass*’ to ‘deriveclass*’ [-fpermissive]
     deriveclass * bb=new baseclass(); //not ok

then **Interviewer tells me which way to access the base class property and method**?

Comment: What? deriveclass cannot allocate baseclass it already inherits from baseclass. If your question is how does a deriveclass access it's baseclass values then you can do deriveclass* b = new deriveclass() and do b->a; since it is public. Remember inheritance means IS-A property. Meaning deriveclass IS A type of BASECLASS so it can access anything from baseclass.

Comment: The question is hard to understand but if the question was geared towards how to access a base class function or variable, then you need the scope resolution operator :: if you want to be explicit. If the functions are public or protected, you can simply invoke them from the child class if the inheritance is public. If you want to call both functions, like I mentioned before, use scope resolution operator ::

Comment: That last line (`//not ok`) makes no sense..Not all animals are cats.

Comment: @Omid CompSCI I defined the already public then I can not access the base class member

Comment: @Paul Renton, I use the  scope resolution operator:: I m trying that but give an error

Comment: I believe your confusion stems from the code example not demonstrating a derived class accessing (or failing to access) a base class member. It tests that while a derived class is-a base class, a base class is-not-a derived class.

Comment: @user4581301 anyway to access base class function or variable?